# missing namespace Cysharp

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, namespaces

I am a little confused. There is a project and different scripts in it. In one of the scripts, a dependency on UniTask:

```
using System.Threading;
using Cysharp.Threading.Tasks;
```

And it works fine:

[image]

Created another script, but now i got missing namespace error:

[image]

As we can see on 1st screenshot: unitask is imported in project.
What i have already done: rebuild solution via VS, but id didnt help.

Any advices please?

Comment: Do you have a reference to the library for the other script?

Comment: is your other script in a different Assembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VS: project - sub folder References - Manage NuGet Packages - add your unitask packages.

for example: dotnet add package UniTask --version 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Solved as:

in VS: project -  Add link - Project - check all unitask - OK